# How to align a mat cross button to the right most of a div in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to create a dismissible message in angular material  and i want to align the mat cross button to the right most of the div , but i can't do that . It is always lying adjacent to the message , here is the code

```
<div *ngIf ="isTrue" class ="my-msg">
  <div class="myContainer">
  <div *ngIf ="isAdded">
    <span> Some text</span>
    <button mat-icon-button-class="close-button" (click)="show()">
     <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
     </button>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
```

The css used

```
.my-msg{
 background-color: ###;
 border: 2px solid ###;
 border-radious:8px;
 padding:5px;
 font-size:124%;
 color:blue;
 }
 
 .myContainer{
  display : flex;
  justify-content : space-between;
  align-items: center;
  }
```

I need the cross button at the end of the message which is showing , any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to control alignment in HTML/CSS, and probably thousands of existing examples on StackOverflow that you could also reference.  Here are the first three that come to mind, in order from (in my opinion) best to worst:

```css
.container1{
  display: flex;
}

.container1 > span{
  flex: 1;
}

.container2{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.container2 > button{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}

.container3{
  display: block;
}

.container3 > button{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <span>some text</span>
  <button>
    A button
  </button>
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <span>some text</span>
  <button>
    A button
  </button>
</div>

<div class="container3">
  <span>some text</span>
  <button>
    A button
  </button>
</div>
```

I will also note that your original code (at least the CSS) has a number of errors in it that you should look into cleaning up.